# Apply function with several input parameters to vector

Tags: r, dataframe, function, input, sapply

I wrote a function `stats.calc(tr,pr)` with two input parameters.

If `stats.calc()` has only one input parameter, I can use:

```
trrange <- seq(0.05,0.9,0.01)

df <- sapply(trrange, stats.calc) |> t() |> as.data.frame()
```

to apply this function to a vector.

Is there a possibility to use this line for the function with two input parameters?

Let me know if this question is unclear!

Comment: If you are trying to iterate over two arguments in parallel, you could use `mapply`: `mapply(stats.calc, trrange, prrange)`

Comment: please share one or two examples of the desired use case, otherwise we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

sapply takes (...) arguments so its relatively trivial. for example

```
add_what <- function(x,what){
  x+what
}

sapply(1:3,add_what,what=4)
```

perhaps you want to ask something more complex, depending on whether the second parameter varies in some way, or is to come from data in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an index:

```
trrange <- seq(0.05,0.9,0.01)
prrange <- seq(5,90,1)


df <- sapply(1:length(trrange), 
      function(i) stats.calc(trrange[i], prrange[i]))
```

It depends on the nature of your problem, e.g. is `prrange` of the same length as `trrange`? If not, you may need to add repeats or if `pr` is just a single value, you don't need to index it at all. In that case the answer by Nir Graham will work. Using `function(i)` makes the approach more generic.